# Searching Coq libraries

Tags: coq

I'm trying to prove that `n <= 2^n` in Coq, and I'm missing a simple lemma that must exist somewhere:

```
a <= b /\ c <= d -> a+c <= b+d
```

Even more generally, how can I search Coq libraries for lemmas like this one?
Here is my code for completeness:

```
(***********)
(* imports *)
(***********)
Require Import Nat.
Require Import Init.Nat.
Require Import Coq.Arith.PeanoNat.

(************************)
(* exponential function *)
(************************)
Definition f (a : nat) : nat := 2^a.

(**********************)
(* inequality theorem *)
(**********************)
Theorem a_leq_pow_2_a: forall a, a <= f(a).
Proof.
  induction a as[|a' IHa].
  - apply le_0_n.
  - unfold f.
    rewrite Nat.pow_succ_r.
    * rewrite Nat.mul_comm.
      rewrite Nat.mul_succ_r.
      rewrite Nat.mul_1_r.
      unfold f in IHa.
      (* stuck here *)
Qed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command for searching lemmas is called `Search`. (For older Coq versions, it was split into `SearchAbout`, `SearchPattern`, etc.) See the [documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/vernacular-commands.html#coq:cmd.search) for all the possible variants.

In your case, you are looking for a lemma with a consequent of the form `_+_ <= _+_`. So, you can type the following, which will give six results, including the one you are looking for:

```
Search (_ + _ <= _ + _).
(*
Nat.add_le_mono_r: forall n m p : nat, n <= m <-> n + p <= m + p
Nat.add_le_mono: forall n m p q : nat, n <= m -> p <= q -> n + p <= m + q
...
*)
```